# Debug Assertion Failed, Expression stream != nullptr

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Using Visual Studio IDE, writing in C. Program is reading in a basic .txt file, converting from Fahrenheit to Celsius, and writing to  new .txt file  Why wont it find the .txt file? Here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
double tempArray[30];
double temp;
double sum = 0;
int input_status;
int count = 0;
double convert;
FILE *infile, *outfile;
infile = fopen("temperature.txt", "r");
if (infile == NULL) {
    perror("Failed: ");
    return 1;
}
outfile = fopen("results.txt", "w");

int i = 0;
input_status = fscanf(infile, "%lf", &temp);
double max, min = temp;
while (input_status != EOF)
{

    tempArray[i] = (temp - 32) * 5 / 9; ;
    sum += tempArray[i];

    fprintf(outfile, "%f \n", tempArray[i]);

    if (tempArray[i] > max)
        max = tempArray[i];

    if (tempArray[i] < min)
        min = tempArray[i];

    count++;
    i++;

    input_status = fscanf(infile, "%lf", &temp);

}

double average = sum / count;

fprintf(outfile, "\n The average of the temperatures is %f \n", average);
fprintf(outfile, "\n The maximum of the temperatures is %f \n", max);
fprintf(outfile, "\n The minimum of the temperatures is %f \n", min);

fclose(infile);
fclose(outfile);
system("pause");
```

}

[here's where the .txt file is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo1Zg.jpg)

[this is the error code i received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BykpC.jpg)

Comment: You are not checking whether `fopen` succeeds or not. Looks like the `fopen` for the result has failed.

Comment: And please don't post text messages as images. Paste it as text into the question so that others can more easily copy it for referencing in comments/answers.

Comment: even if i check if it successfully opens, that will not change why it is not successful. Why is it not finding the .txt file?

Comment: The file name that you pass to `fopen` is relative to the *current working directory*. When debugging, there's a project setting that allows you to point the *current working directory* to whatever directory you like. You can also change the *current working directory* from within your program (using `chdir` on unix-like systems). If the file that you want to open is not in the *current working directory*, then you need to specify the full path to the file, e.g. `fopen("c:\\projects\\TempRecorder\\temperature.txt","r");`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I named the file "temperature.txt" and is was already a .txt file, so the file name was actually "temperature.txt.txt". Small mistake, big problem. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

The executable that runs is in the Debug folder (in this case), so `temperature.txt` needs to be in that folder, or it needs to be `"..\temperature.txt"` or similar passed into `fopen()`.

Comment: I'm not seeing what kaylum is seeing, so I can't help with that.  But as another observation, you show `temperature.txt` in `Projects\TempRecorder.c\TempRecorder.c\ ` but the executable in `Projects\TempRecorder.c\Debug\ `, so the relative path for `fopen()` would actually be `..\TempRecorder.c\temperature.txt` in that case.

Comment: so i have to put the whole path starting from my c drive or to put in in debug correct? because i tried both and still cannot get it to run